# Comparing char with enum

Tags: objective-c, enums, c99

I have an enum defined this way:

```
typedef enum : unsigned char {
    START_DELIMITER = 0xAA,
    END_DELIMITER   = 0xBB,
} Delimiter;
```

When I compare the delimiter value with with char byte from const char*, like so:

```
// data is NSData;
const char *bytes = [data bytes];
if (bytes[0] == START_DELIMITER) { }
```

The above test is false even though bytes[0] contains 0xAA.

If I define START_DELIMITER as const char, the comparison is true.  Why does the test against the enum fails even though the enum is already defined as unsigned char?

Comment: I'm guessing `char` is signed on your implementation and `0xAA` can't fit in it.

Comment: Why use a enum for this? Why not declare a set of constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The char is signed, and the enum is unsigned.  Perhaps the compiler sign-extends before making the comparison?